# In Rails change the display value while using an iteration and enum?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There are four possible options for status: confirmed, pending, rejected, and removal. They are actually represented as integers but the model has the following:

```
class UTR < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :training_resource
 enum status: [:pending, :confirmed, :rejected, :removal]
 module SameScope
  HR = ['pending', 'confirmed', 'rejected', 'removal'].freeze
 end
end
```

The front end is using 'removal' as a check for building out their side so I don't really want to update the language here. But we have a form that's being used on the backend to update the status and it needs to change from Removal to Request for Removal.

The form looks like:

```
<%= tb_form_for [:admin, x], url: admin_update_utr_path(x), :remote => true, data: {errors: :inline, success: admin_training_resource_path(@training_resource)} do |f| %>
 <%= f.select :status, UserTrainingResource.statuses.map {|k,v| [k.humanize, k]}%>
<%= f.submit 'Save', class: 'btn btn-primary'%>
<% end %>
```

I know the k is pulling in the current status. Is there a way to put a condition on it to display a different value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `.humanize` on the keys, check the docks here to understand what it does https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-humanize

There are a lot of options to do what you want, I guess the best practice is to use translations.

the form (just moved that logic to a helper to make it cleaner):

```
<%= select :status, user_training_resource_select_statuses %>
```

application_helper:

```
def user_training_resource_select_statuses
  UserTrainingResource.statuses.map{|k,v| [I18n.t(k), k]}
end
```

locale/en.yml:

```
en:
  pending: Pending
  confirmed: Confirmed
  rejected: Rejected
  removal: Request to Removal
```

Now the view does not handle logic (easier to test), the helper does that. And the I18n module handles the names.

You can use different helpers for frontend and backend, one could use I18n and the other humanize; or you can use I18n on both with the same helper and use scoping to handle different translations

```
<%= select :status, user_training_resource_select_statuses(:frontend) %>

<%= select :status, user_training_resource_select_statuses(:backend) %>

def user_training_resource_select_statuses(scope)
  UserTrainingResource.statuses.map{|k,v| [I18n.t(k, scope: scope), k]}
end

en:
  frontend:
    pending: Pending
    confirmed: Confirmed
    rejected: Rejected
    removal: Removal
  backend:
    pending: Pending
    confirmed: Confirmed
    rejected: Rejected
    removal: Request to Removal
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be tempted to build a class method that gives me the correct prompts, and call that in the view.

```
class UserTrainingResourc < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :training_resource
  enum status: [:pending, :confirmed, :rejected, :removal]

  BACKEND_STATUS_PROMPTS{:removal => 'Request for removal'}

  def self.backend_status_options
    UserTrainingResource.statuses.map{|k, _v| [(BACKEND_STATUS_PROMPTS[k] || k.humanize), k]}
  end

  module SameScope
    HR = ['pending', 'confirmed', 'rejected', 'removal'].freeze
  end
end
```

So  you can then do

```
<%= f.select :status, UserTrainingResource.backend_status_options %>
```